# Is canonical cover always unique for any relationship?

Tags: database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, bcnf

Suppose I have the following relationship

```
C -> B
CB -> AC
CAE -> FB
D -> E
CA -> B
```

Canonical cover given in my book is `C -> AB, CE -> F, D -> E`

But Canonical cover can also be `C - AB, D - EF?` Can we have two different canonical cover for one relationship?

Comment: *"Canonical cover given in my book is C -> AB, CE -> D, D -> E"* What happened to "F"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But Canonical cover can also be `C - AB`, `D - EF`?

**No**, it cannot be a canonical cover for your set of functional dependencies (FD). *A canonical cover of F is a “minimal” set of functional 
dependencies **equivalent to F**, having no redundant dependencies or redundant parts of dependencies.*

The canonical cover you suggest is not equivalent to `F`. For instance the functional dependency `CAE->FB` is not fully covered in the canonical cover suggested by you and hence it is not a canonical cover.

On the other hand the one given in your book `C -> AB, CE -> F, D -> E` is a canonical cover and the **only** canonical cover possible for this set of FD's.

> Can we have two different canonical cover for one relationship?

**Yes** we can. To find *canonical cover* we do -

- **First** ensure singleton right-hand side (RHS)
- **Second** remove any extraneous left-hand side (LHS) attribute
- **Third** remove any redundant functional dependency

*We can have different canonical cover for one relationship because of the third step above.* I will explain this with an example.

Given FD's as:

```
X→YZ
Y→XZ
Z→XY
```

**First** ensure singleton RHS. So we have :

1. X→Y
2. X→Z
3. Y→X
4. Y→Z
5. Z→X
6. Z→Y

**Second** No extraneous LHS. Already satisfied.

**Third** Remove any redundant FD. Now we can remove (2),(3) and (6) as redundant dependencies and have the minimal cover set as:

**1:**

```
X→Y,
Y→Z,
Z→X
```

or we can remove (1),(4) and (5) as redundant dependencies and have the minimal cover set as:

**2:**

```
Z→Y,
Y→X,
X→Z
```

Hence, in this case we have two canonical covers for the same relationship.

Comment: Thanks @PuRaK your answer is so helpful

Comment: Also watch this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8j4lYeVIek). Nicely explained the steps to find canonical cover

Comment: @Karup can we have canonical covers of different size?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a set of functional dependencies (not *a relationship*) can have multiple canonical covers. Date gives a step-by-step derivation in the answer to exercise 10.12 in *An Introduction to Database Systems*, 7th ed., p346f.

Date doesn't use the term *canonical cover*. He uses *irreducible cover*, more or less.

Comment: Then we will have different BCNF cover also ?